# HCC Runtime Error when trying to run hipTensorFlow (Ubuntu 16.04, R9 290)

Tags: tensorflow, ubuntu-16.04, amd-processor, hip

I installed hipTensorFlow following the instructions [here.](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/hiptensorflow/blob/hip/rocm_docs/tensorflow-install-basic.md)

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 as they say in the guide and I have an AMD R9 290 card.

But when attempting to import Tensorflow I get the following output:

```
>>> import tensorflow

Backtrace:
0x00007f87e0b6800e: Kalmar::CLAMP::DetermineAndGetProgram(Kalmar::KalmarQueue*, unsigned long*, void**) + 0x59e
0x00007f87e0b68370: Kalmar::KalmarBootstrap::KalmarBootstrap() + 0x120
0x00007f87e0b68229: __hcc_shared_library_init + 0x29
0x00007f87efb7a6ba: _dl_rtld_di_serinfo + 0x706a
0x00007f87efb7a7cb: _dl_rtld_di_serinfo + 0x717b
0x00007f87efb7f8e2: _dl_find_dso_for_object + 0xcf2
0x00007f87efb7a564: _dl_rtld_di_serinfo + 0x6f14
0x00007f87efb7eda9: _dl_find_dso_for_object + 0x1b9
0x00007f87ef37ff09: <unknown function> + 0x1b9
0x00007f87efb7a564: _dl_rtld_di_serinfo + 0x6f14
0x00007f87ef380571: dlerror + 0x2c1
0x00007f87ef37ffa1: dlopen + 0x31
0x00000000005231c3: _PyImport_GetDynLoadFunc + 0xf3
0x0000000000522d6f: _PyImport_LoadDynamicModule + 0x4f
0x00000000005c7175: _PyInt_FromUid + 0x145
0x00000000004c468a: PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 0x68a
0x00000000004c9d8f: PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 0x5d8f
0x00000000004c2765: PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 0x255
0x00000000004c2509: PyEval_EvalCode + 0x19
0x00000000004c061b: PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 0xcb
0x00000000004bd6ee: _PyObject_RealIsSubclass + 0x3be
0x00000000004afbad: _PyImport_AcquireLock + 0x1bd
0x00000000004af7e9: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 0xd59
0x00000000004b0f78: PyCFunction_Call + 0x248
0x00000000004b0cb3: PyObject_Call + 0x43
0x00000000004ce5d0: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 0x30
0x00000000004c6ed6: PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 0x2ed6
0x00000000004c2765: PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 0x255
0x00000000004c2509: PyEval_EvalCode + 0x19
0x00000000004c061b: PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 0xcb
0x00000000004bd6ee: _PyObject_RealIsSubclass + 0x3be
0x00000000004be9e7: PyEval_GetRestricted + 0x167
0x00000000004afbad: _PyImport_AcquireLock + 0x1bd
0x00000000004af34d: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 0x8bd
0x00000000004b0f78: PyCFunction_Call + 0x248
0x00000000004b0cb3: PyObject_Call + 0x43
0x00000000004ce5d0: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 0x30
0x00000000004c6ed6: PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 0x2ed6
0x00000000004c2765: PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 0x255
0x00000000004c2509: PyEval_EvalCode + 0x19
0x00000000004c061b: PyImport_ExecCodeModuleEx + 0xcb
0x00000000004bd6ee: _PyObject_RealIsSubclass + 0x3be
0x00000000004be9e7: PyEval_GetRestricted + 0x167
0x00000000004af215: PyImport_ImportModuleLevel + 0x785
0x00000000004b0f78: PyCFunction_Call + 0x248
0x00000000004b0cb3: PyObject_Call + 0x43
0x00000000004ce5d0: PyEval_CallObjectWithKeywords + 0x30
0x00000000004c6ed6: PyEval_EvalFrameEx + 0x2ed6
0x00000000004c2765: PyEval_EvalCodeEx + 0x255
0x00000000004c2509: PyEval_EvalCode + 0x19
0x00000000004f1def: PyIter_Next + 0x23f
0x000000000044c6ed: PyRun_InteractiveOneFlags + 0x199
0x000000000044c4b2: PyRun_InteractiveLoopFlags + 0xc6
0x000000000042e88a: Py_FatalError + 0xcd8d
0x000000000049e14a: Py_Main + 0x68a
0x00007f87ef5a3830: __libc_start_main + 0xf0
0x000000000049d9d9: _start + 0x29

### HCC RUNTIME ERROR: Fail to find compatible kernel at file:mcwamp.cpp line:346
```

Attempting to search this in Google didn't yield much help - is it just that my card is not supported or is there something I can do to help it work?

Comment: I have the R9 390X (so essentially the same card) with a clean Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and I have the same issue. I'm using the 4.11.0-kfd-compute-rocm-rel-1.6-180 kernel. I followed the installation exactly and hipInfo correctly returns all data.